# git: Event trigger on push

Tags: linux, bash, git, gitlab

I'm wondering if there's a way to detect when I commit and push code.

The idea came because I'm greedy and I want my GitHub to reflect my "code productivity" but we use gitlab at work and I wanted to write a little bash script that detects when I push and updates a phony private github repo on github.

I've looked online but couldn't find event driven workflows for git.
Where do I start ?

Answer (score 1):

> I've looked online but couldn't find event driven workflows for git.

You can use a *GitLab* event-driven workflow, with [GitLab CI/CD pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/).

For instance, [`IlyaSemenov/gitlab-ci-git-push`](https://github.com/IlyaSemenov/gitlab-ci-git-push) will push your commits done on GitLab `main` to another repository of your choice.